# Need Ideas On How To Pull Dated Records From A Table Using Cognos inside of Ultimate Over SQL

Tags: sql, cognos

I'm using Cognos 10 Query Studio inside of an Ultimate platform that is over an SQL server.

Basically, I have a table with Gross Pay Per Pay Period by Employee.  The table looks like this:

```
Employee1 - PayPeriodStateDate1 - PayPeriodEndDate1 - PayDate1 - GrossPay1
Employee1 - PayPeriodStateDate2 - PayPeriodEndDate2 - PayDate2 - GrossPay2
Employee1 - PayPeriodStateDate3 - PayPeriodEndDate3 - PayDate3 - GrossPay3
Employee2 - PayPeriodStateDate1 - PayPeriodEndDate1 - PayDate1 - GrossPay1
Employee2 - PayPeriodStateDate2 - PayPeriodEndDate2 - PayDate2 - GrossPay2
Employee2 - PayPeriodStateDate3 - PayPeriodEndDate3 - PayDate3 - GrossPay3
```

Etc... Except there are thousands of employees and thousands of pay periods over about two decades.

I need to pull a list that has the average of the 52 most recent records (past two years) for each employee.  Obviously, this would be pretty easy if every employee has an unbroken time of service.  I could just take current_date - 2 years, right?

The problem is that many employees leave and come back.  If Joe Blow left from July 2015 to November 2015 (ten pay periods), he would get the average of his pay over the previous 42 pay periods.

I'm pretty sure I can use SQL in queries in this Cognos environment.  How can I pull a list of all the records from the previous two years, count the number of records, and divide the totals of these records by the number I counted?  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I dont know much about Cognos and what is available from sql server, but a sql server window function could knock this out.  You would partition the results by employee, order by most recent paydate, and then grab the top 52 results from that set and average.  Again, I do not know if this is even compatible, just a thought.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I can write SQL in these queries.  I've used other, simpler, SQL commands.  I've only been working in this system for a few days so I'm not really sure what it can and can't do.  My problem is that I'm not that great at SQL.  I couldn't do this in an SQL only environment.  Would I create a derived table by using Select and Group By?

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses Common Table Expressions (CTE's) and window functions to find your average gross pay for the 52 most recent records.  The first CTE will grab all your employees, grab all their related pay amounts, and then rank them from most recent to oldest.  The 2nd CTE will use that result set to grab all records that are within the 52 most recent range.  The final part of the query will use that record set to average the amount for each employee.  I didnt make temp tables to check data, but it parses fine.  Please let me know how it goes.

```
;with EmpRanking AS (
SELECT 
employeeID
, grosspay
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY employeeID ORDER BY paydate desc) AS record_Counter

FROM your_table)

, EmpRanking52 AS (
SELECT employeeID
, grosspay
, record_counter

FROM EmpRanking

WHERE record_counter <= 52)

SELECT employeeID
, AVG(GrossPay) AS avg_pay

FROM EmpRanking52

GROUP BY employeeID
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm walking out of the office now, but I'll play around with this and give it a try first thing in the morning.

Comment: As a pure Cognos alternative, you could replace the CTEs with queries in Cognos.  Your first query would be the same as `EmpRanking`, your second query would query from query one, etc.